# Random variables i.i.d. conditional on others

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, independence

Consider the random variables $\{X,Y\}_{i=1}^n$ defined on the same probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ are i.i.d. across $i$. $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^n$ are i.i.d. across $i$ ***conditional on $X_1,...,X_n$***.

Let $\mathcal{N}:=\{1,2,...,N\}$ and consider $\varphi:\mathcal{N}\rightarrow \mathcal{N}$ being a bijective function representing a permutation of labels.

Supposing for simplicity that the random variables are discrete and $n=4$, is it true that

(*)
$$
P(Y_1=1,Y_2=2, Y_3=3, Y_4=4|X_1=a, X_2=b, X_3=c, X_4=d)=P(Y_{\varphi(1)}=1,Y_{\varphi(2)}=2, Y_{\varphi(3)}=3, Y_{\varphi(4)}=4|X_{\varphi(1)}=a, X_{\varphi(2)}=b, X_{\varphi(3)}=c, X_{\varphi(4)}=d)
$$
?
I believe the answer is yes because

(i) using $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^n$ i.i.d. across $i$ conditional on $X_1,...,X_n$
$$
P(Y_1=1,Y_2=2, Y_3=3, Y_4=4|X_1=a, X_2=b, X_3=c, X_4=d)=P(Y_{\varphi(1)}=1,Y_{\varphi(2)}=2, Y_{\varphi(3)}=3, Y_{\varphi(4)}=4|X_1=a, X_2=b, X_3=c, X_4=d)
$$

(ii) Using $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ i.i.d. across $i$
 $$
P(Y_{\varphi(1)}=1,Y_{\varphi(2)}=2, Y_{\varphi(3)}=3, Y_{\varphi(4)}=4|X_1=a, X_2=b, X_3=c, X_4=d)=P(Y_{\varphi(1)}=1,Y_{\varphi(2)}=2, Y_{\varphi(3)}=3, Y_{\varphi(4)}=4|X_{\varphi(1)}=a, X_{\varphi(2)}=b, X_{\varphi(3)}=c, X_{\varphi(4)}=d)
$$

Correct?

Comment: ?? The fact that $(X_i)$ is i.i.d. certainly does not imply your (ii).

Comment: Assume that $n=2$, $Y_1=X_1+7X_2+Z_1$ and $Y_2=X_1+7X_2+Z_2$ where $(X_1,X_2)$ is i.i.d, $(Z_1,Z_2)$ is i.i.d., and $(X_1,X_2)$ and $(Z_1,Z_2)$ are independent. Let $p$ denote the common distribution of $Z_1$ and $Z_2$, then $$P(Y_1=y_1,Y_2=y_2\mid X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2)=p(y_1-x_1-7x_2)p(y_2-x_1-7x_2)$$ while, using the permutation $\varphi=(12)$, $$P(Y_2=y_1,Y_1=y_2\mid X_2=x_1,X_1=x_2)=p(y_1-7x_1-x_2)p(y_2-7x_1-x_2)$$ hence these do not coincide in general.

Comment: @Did the statement (*) holds instead if $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^n$ are i.i.d. across $i$ (unconditionally of $X_1,...,X_n$), correct?

Comment: Also, is (i) correct instead?